# /p:AssemblyVersion doesn't override AssemblyInfo.cs parameters

Tags: msbuild, azure-pipelines, .net-assembly, msbuild-task

I want my Azure pipeline to override the `[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.1.6.0")]` and `[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.1.6.0")]` fields located in `AssemblyInfo.cs`. In the build task I use this configuration:

```
- task: MSBuild@1
    inputs:
      solution: '*.csproj'
      msbuildArguments:'/p:OutputPath=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) /p:AssemblyVersion="$(Build.BuildNumber)"'
```

but the version of the assembly remains the same, instead I want them to become equal to the current build number. Why don't the values update?

Comment: /p lets you override MSBuild properties, not code.

Comment: @HansPassant thanks. So, how should I do?

Comment: You've only shown how not to do it, we can't tell why this is necessary and where the number comes from.  Google "c# set assembly version at build time" to get ahead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To update AssemblyVersion you can use [Assembly Info](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bleddynrichards.Assembly-Info-Task&targetId=47097972-e633-4284-ad72-fe49f3c8dd5f) task in your pipeline.

You need first install this task, go the **Marketplace** on the top right corner, and search for Assembly Info.

This task contains two sub tasks. **Assembly-Info-NetFramework task** for NetFramwork project. and **Assembly-Info-NetCore@2** task for NetCore project.

[image]

For below example to add this task to your pipeline before build task.

```
 - task: Assembly-Info-NetFramework@2
      inputs:
        FileNames: "**/AssemblyInfo.cs"
        VersionNumber: $(Build.BuildNumber)
```